# How to reindex a dataframe by its values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
country  doctor  teacher  lawyer
China      41       26      34
USA        25       29      40
Japan      20       26      27
```

I have a dataframe above, how to convert it to the following one?

```
age job country
41  doctor  China
25  doctor  USA
20  doctor  Japan
26  teacher China
29  teacher USA
26  teacher Japan
34  lawyer  China
40  lawyer  USA
27  lawyer  Japan
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.set_index('country').stack()
```

(Or you might really want `df.set_index('country').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'job', 0: 'age'})` to take the question more literally -- details depend on what you're doing.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `set_index` and `unstack` for that:

```
In [65]: df.set_index('country').unstack().reset_index()
Out[65]:
   level_0 country   0
0   doctor   China  41
1   doctor     USA  25
2   doctor   Japan  20
3  teacher   China  26
4  teacher     USA  29
5  teacher   Japan  26
6   lawyer   China  34
7   lawyer     USA  40
8   lawyer   Japan  27
```

Or if you want to `age` be index of your result you could add `set_index`:

```
In [66]: df.set_index('country').unstack().reset_index().set_index(0)
Out[66]:
    level_0 country
0
41   doctor   China
25   doctor     USA
20   doctor   Japan
26  teacher   China
29  teacher     USA
26  teacher   Japan
34   lawyer   China
40   lawyer     USA
27   lawyer   Japan
```

With renaming and reordering columns:

```
res = df.set_index('country').unstack().reset_index()
res.columns = ['job', 'country', 'age']
res = res[['age', 'job', 'country']]

In [73]: res
Out[73]:
   age      job country
0   41   doctor   China
1   25   doctor     USA
2   20   doctor   Japan
3   26  teacher   China
4   29  teacher     USA
5   26  teacher   Japan
6   34   lawyer   China
7   40   lawyer     USA
8   27   lawyer   Japan
```